# Geckodriver is not responding

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I used geckodriver with python selenium. Simple command `driver = Webdriver.Firefox()`, hangs the python script. I debugged and found it is geckodriver not responding. started geckodriver manually and curl does not respond either. But firefox instance is started and ready but the geckodriver did not send any HTTP response. Any ideas on how to debug further? Even if it requires any patching on geckodriver, I would like to try.

```
$ geckodriver --port 57738 &> gecko.log &
[1] 16123
$ jobs
[1]  + running    geckodriver --port 57738 &> gecko.log
$ curl -v --data '{"requiredCapabilities": {}, "desiredCapabilities": {"javascriptEnabled": true, "browserName": "firefox", "version": "", "platform": "ANY", "marionette": true}}' http://127.0.0.1:57738/session
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 57738 (#0)
> POST /session HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:57738
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 160
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 160 out of 160 bytes
```

gecko.log

```
$ cat gecko.log 
1479507861533   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:57738
1479507874758   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path /tmp/rust_mozprofile.fkk6AqrNIGxB
1479507874759   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser /usr/bin/firefox
1479507874763   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:36577
+ exec /usr/bin/firefox.real --marionette --profile /tmp/rust_mozprofile.fkk6AqrNIGxB

(firefox:16144): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:16144): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:16144): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:16144): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
1479507875413   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 36577
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what are the geckodeiver, Firefox and Selenium versions you are using?

Comment: selenium  '3.0.1'
geckodriver 'v0.11.1'
firefox 50.0
I just tried again and I no longer see this issue now. This is transient :(

Comment: As geckdriver is not yet feature complete and you are using the latest Firefox browser, it might be compatibility issue. Always keep in mind. Always use latest geckodriver if you are using Firefox 48 and onwards.

Comment: I suspect it's the same as what I got - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789893 - hoping it'll go away for me too...